# Cant get the copy/assign constructors working

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I am making a MFC like class build on the WinAPI as an exersise. 
Now am i running into the problem that i am getting a runtime error while i execute the code.

In My Main the following lines are present:

```
void MyApp::Init(int nCmd)
{
    main.Create(L"This is the MainFrame Window");
    main.ActivateFrame(nCmd);   
    GWnd* p= main.GetActiveView();//Get pointer to the first view of the FrameWnd
    //p->GetID();
}
```

The commented out line causes the error.
The GWnd class constructors:

```
//Standard classname
GWnd::GWnd() :m_ClassName(L"Wnd"), BaseWnd(), m_pOwnerWnd(NULL)
{
    GWnd::Init();
}
//Userdefined Classname
GWnd::GWnd(LPCWSTR ClassName) : m_ClassName(ClassName), BaseWnd(), m_pOwnerWnd(NULL)
{
    GWnd::Init();
}
//Copy constructor
GWnd::GWnd(const GWnd& Wnd) : BaseWnd(GetHwnd()), m_pOwnerWnd(NULL)
{
    m_ClassName = L"Wnd";
}
```

The assignment function:

```
//Operators
operator HWND() { return BaseWnd<GWnd>::GetHwnd(); }
GWnd operator=(GWnd Wnd) 
{
    GWnd tmp(Wnd);
}
```

I hope the lines of code are sufficient for your answers. Does someone understands the issue i am running into? And could give me a hint where to look further?

Comment: I assume the error is that P is NULL and you're dereferencing the NULL pointer?  Nowhere in the code above are you actually construction an instance  (at least not in Init)

Comment: Why does your assignment operator not return a value when you specifically stated that it returns a `GWnd` object?  Also, do you know the purpose of a copy constructor and assignment operator?  It's purpose is to make a copy of the passed in object -- I fail to see that happening in your copy constructor.

Comment: So `p` is `NULL`? Have you read the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs0t7t34.aspx) about how this could be the case?

Comment: You should probably make this noncopyable and non-assignable ; you need to create windows using `CreateWindow` or another WinAPI function

Comment: I realize that i might have given too less code in the above snippets. @KirkSpaziani: The pointer does not return NULL. The value is the correct addres to the MyView instance (That is what the function GetActiveView() in this case should return. The Call to GetID() makes use of ::GetDlgCtrlID(). It uses a member of the baseclass of GWnd to get the HWND of that window. When i check that, its not the same as the HWND of the Active View. My feeling is that that is causing the problem. Hence my conclusion was that something is wrong with assigning or copying the instances.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: So you say I forgot a return keyword....I tried to use the copyconstructor to make a new GWnd instance with input of the Wnd instance. I also thought that a copy constructor is assigning the members of the copied instance to the new one. Members are: m_hwnd (set by GetHwnd() in the BaseWnd, Owner is set to NULL and m_ClassName is set to "Wnd". Could you hint me if i took the complete wrong approach to this problem?

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I want to assign a pointer (p) with the address of the Active View. And the use this pointer to access the functions of the instance of the active view. I first thought that I did not need any copy or assignments, but that did not work either. Of course I am not copyying windows, the class does use the WinApi calls and that works fine, except the commented out call with pointer p

Comment: Looking again at my code i realize that I think that GetActiveView() is returnin a pointer to type GWnd. debugging shows that the address is correct (I wrote down the address of the "this" pointer at creation). My assigment operator is 1) lacking a return and 2) not accepting a pointer as parameter. I think the same is true for the copy constructor. I am not sure if it is allowed to use pointers here....I also thought it would not be necessary to do something, because all i want is a pointer to an excisting instance.

Comment: @gedysan - First, not returning a value from a function that returns a value is `undefined behavior`, therefore right away, your assignment operator is incorrect.  Second, a copy constructor and assignment operator's purpose is to make an *exact* copy of the passed-in object.  You should just assign the value of m_ClassName to whatever the value is in the object passed to you -- don't assume it is always "Wnd".  Last, you need to decide what it means to "make a copy".  If there is no clear definition of what that means, then make your object non-copyable.

Comment: @gedysan - I believe your issue is simply this -- it isn't a coding issue, it is an issue in you not having a clear knowledge of what it means to copy your object.  You're juggling pointers around, calling functions, and doing all sorts of "business logic".  But that is *not* the purpose of a copy constructor and assignment operator.  It should be simple thing, but it doesn't seem so.  So maybe the best advice to you is "don't do it"  -- just make your object non-copyable.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I feel getting my cheeks getting red....I will get into this and try to report back on what I changed. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I thought i needed to use it because of the next statement:The copy constructor is called whenever an object is initialized from another object of the same type, which includes

    initialization, T a = b; or T a(b);, where b is of type T. But i think this is not working with pointers?

Comment: Your assignment/copy constructors are not invoked on a pointer assignment, correct.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this:

```
GWnd* p= (GWnd*)main.GetActiveView();
```

instead of this:

```
GWnd* p= main.GetActiveView();
```

and then use this

```
p->GetDlgCtrlID()
```

Comment: don't C-style cast in C++

Comment: @RyanHaining: Why not?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Don't C-style cast is good advice in general, IMO. Use `dynamic_cast` and `const_cast` when more appropriate. `reinterpret_cast` is more descriptive about *intent*

Comment: @AndyG: Actually, you want `static_cast` there. And I just objected because there are many situations in which not using a c-style (or function-style) cast is more verbose without offering any compensation.

Comment: @Deduplicator, what do you mean by: _without offering any compensation_

Comment: What is better: `(void*)0` or `static_cast<void*>(0)`? The second is three times as long and no clearer, the extra-text obscuring that it's just a null pointer of specific type. That's a situation where "The 'new' casts are more readable, because there is so much more to read." fits.

Comment: @Samer: I actually did try that. I makes no difference. I think the assignment operator should do the "casting". And that is not going like I am expecting. The pointer p is in both cases of the correct type with the correct address.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Whoops, I certainly meant to say that instead of `const_cast`. I actually really don't like `const_cast`